# Возведение последовательности чисел в степень

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть последовательность чисел `[0,1,2,3,4..n]`. Как её можно задать, после чего каждое число возвести в определенную степень (например, во вторую)?
Т.е. на экран должен выводиться ответ вида `[0,1,4,9...]`.

Я так понимаю, это работа с массивами?

Comment: Это работа с циклами, и на msdn готовый пример. Ищи Math.Pow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На экран результат можно выводить и без использования массива. А именно перебирать последовательно идущие числа в цикле, возводить их в нужную степень и выводить результат сразу на экран.

Для возведения в степень используется метод `Math.Pow`.

```
int n = 10;
int power = 2;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    Console.Write(Math.Pow(i, power) + " ");
}
```

---

Если результирующие числа нужные ещё для чего-то, то действительно имеет смысл сохранить их в массиве:

```
int n = 10;
int power = 2;
double[] result = new double[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    result[i] = Math.Pow(i, power);
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", result));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//Задаёте последовательность в виде массива целочисленных переменных, инициализируя массив при объявлении
var numberArray = new int[] { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 };

//т.к. массив реализует IEnumerable, можно воспользоваться циклом foreach
foreach (var number in numberArray)
{
    //Выводим в консоль значение каждой переменной из последовательности, предворительно возводя её во вторую степень при помощи Math.Pow()
    Console.Write(Math.Pow(number, 2) + " ");
}
```

Comment: хорошо, а как работать с большими числами? Я думал, что можно будет просто сделать вот так `var numberArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };          
            foreach (var number in numberArray)
            {
                Console.Write(BigInteger.Pow(number, n) + " ");
            }` где n какое-нибудь большое число, но так не получается, выдает ошибку, что _не удается преобразовать из "System.Numerics.BigInteger" в "int"_. Простите, что задаю возможно такие глупые вопросы, но просто я в этом плохо разбираюсь((

Comment: Достаточно везде заменить int на long.